# nested relationship Laravel Eloquent query

Tags: nested, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5

i've a 3 Models : Pizzerie , Pizze , Ingredients each has his own relationships

```
class Pizzerie extends Model {
  protected $table = 'pizzerie';
  public function pizze()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Pizze', 'pizzerie_id');
  }
}

class Pizze extends Model {
  protected $table = 'pizze';
  public function ingredienti()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredienti', 'pizze_ingredienti');
  }
  public function pizzeria()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Pizzerie');
  }
}

class Ingredienti extends Model {
  protected $table = 'ingredienti';
  public function pizze()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pizze', 'pizze_ingredienti');
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a query that allow me to loop in my view like this

```
@foreach($data as $pizzeria)
<p>{{ $pizzeria->name }} Has pizze: </p>
  @foreach($pizzeria as $pizze)
  <p>{{ $pizza->name }} Has ingredients: </p>
    <ul>
    @foreach($pizza as $ingredient)
    <li>{{ $ingredient->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Can't figure out how to get it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will get the next relation Collection in each of the foreach loops.

```
@foreach($data as $pizzeria)
<p>{{ $pizzeria->name }} Has pizze: </p>
  @foreach($pizzeria->pizze as $pizze)
  <p>{{ $pizza->name }} Has ingredients: </p>
    <ul>
    @foreach($pizze->ingredienti as $ingredient)
    <li>{{ $ingredient->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: what should i query ? $data = \App\pizzerie::all();  ?

Comment: Correct, this is how you get the all of the pizzerias.

Comment: $data = \App\pizzerie::with('pizze.ingredienti')->get();

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment to Margus Pala's answers :( but your query should like

```
$data = \App\pizzerie::with('pizze. ingredienti')->get();
```

because of the eager loading problem, this is important problem (too many query in loop)

[Eager loading in documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading)